# Getting iOS Video Asset orientation

Tags: video, ios4, orientation, video-capture

How can you get the orientation of a video from the assets library?

All the information I get out of the video file shows me the property for orientation is always 0.

Is there anyone who has checked the video orientation from videos that were created using the camera? I'm looking for any solution.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because orientation 0 - Portrait with the home button at the bottom
1 = Portrait (top home button)
2 = Landscape (left home button)
3 = Landscape (right home button)

looks like all the videos you have watched so far have been recorded at orientation 0, which is having the device in portrait mode. lol i record all my videos like that so i guess my videos will also have the 0 property.

**PK**